# Can you nest a "double cons" pattern match?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I want to strengthen a pattern to match only numbers which pass an additional validation function.

```
let (|IsValid|_|) n = ...

let (|Nil|One|Two|) (l : int list) =
    match l with 
    | a :: b :: t -> Two(a + b)
    | a :: t      -> One(a)
    | _           -> Nil
```

The 'One' case is easy:

```
    | IsValid(a) :: t -> One(a)
```

The 'Two' case isn't obvious to me. It needs to validate the sum of the numbers. Can I do this without using a when-guard?

...

Edit: I could use a when-guard (with a bool-returning isValid function) like this:

```
    | a :: b :: t when isValid a + b -> Two(a + b)
```

This is less elegant than just matching a pattern; worse, a + b is applied twice.

Also note this is a simplified version of my actual code (I'm not trying to simply match against different lengths of list for example) - the question is about nested matching over the double cons pattern.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you're asking, nor do I know how you want to validate your numbers. It would help if you provided a sample input and an expected output.

Comment: Show us what you think it is with the 'when' clause then we can tell you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution: Add a "helper" recogniser with a return value designed to be used in the parent pattern:

```
let (|MatchTwo|_|) = function
    | a :: b :: t -> Some(a + b :: t)
    | _ -> None
```

Use it like so:

```
let (|Nil|One|Two|) (l : int list) =
    match l with 
    | MatchTwo(IsValid(a) :: t) -> Two(a)
    |          IsValid(a) :: t  -> One(a)
    | _                         -> Nil
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
| a :: b :: t -> ...
```

You aren't necessarily matching two elements in a list. It's better to use `[]` instead of `t` to match two elements exactly --`t` can be a list of more elements.

```
 | a :: b :: [] -> Two (a+b)
```

This will ensure that you are matching two and only two elements --error checking for free! I suggest doing this even though you expect the function to only accept a list of 0, 1, or 2 elements. So,

*EDIT:*

```
let (|MatchTwo|_|) = function
    | a :: b :: t -> Some(a + b :: t)
    | _ -> None
let (|Nil|One|Two|) (l : int list) = match l with 
    | MatchTwo(IsValid(a) :: t) -> Two(a)
    | IsValid(a) :: t  -> One(a)
    | _ -> Nil
```

Yeah, use `when`. This is a mess. Pattern matching is just that, applying functions within the match really doesn't make sense. But take into account what I've mentioned prior. Based on your example:

```
match l with
| a :: b :: t when isValid (a+b) -> Two (a+b)
| a :: t when isValid (a) -> One a
| _ -> Nil
```

The second pattern will match lists of length longer then one if isValid is false on the first pattern --be warned. Be as specific in your patterns as possible, if you mean to match one element, do it.

If whatever operation you use to combine a and b (in this case +) is computationally expensive, then you will have to drop the `when` and use a let statement before testing the isValid and returning the variant type.

Comment: Thanks, but I've maybe simplified my real code badly.  I actually don't want to match a list with only 0, 1 or 2 elements. But this is still completely irrelevant to the question!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound so terse in my last comment! Thanks for taking your time to help me.